# rsyslog - how to install rsyslog-imdocker module?

Tags: log, logging, rsyslog

How to install rsyslog-imdocker module for ubuntu 22.04? Tried different things but still with no luck :(
Besides tried to search for the same package on Centos 8 Stream and still the same results,

Could you please assist with installation?

Comment: Please list everything you have tried and in detail. Include all error messages you have received. What does the discontinued Centos OS have to do with this?

Comment: didn't found the module in any avaialbe repos for Centos 8 Stream & Ubuntu 22.04 :(

Tried to use [repo](https://www.rsyslog.com/rhelcentos-rpms/) but still no luck rsyslog-imdocker is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in ppa:adiscon/v8-stable:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common
add-apt-repository -y ppa:adiscon/v8-stable
apt-get install -y rsyslog-imdocker
```

Stumbled across the answer at https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/tree/v8.2306.0 while trying to get this working on Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Comment: thank you very much :)